# Get only specified fields from MongoDB C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following POCO class in my app -

```
public class Course
{
    public String  Title { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
}
```

But the `Course` collection in mongodb has some other fields also including those. I am trying to get data as follows-

```
var server = MongoServer.Create(connectionString);
var db = _server.GetDatabase("dbName");
db.GetCollection("users");

var cursor = Photos.FindAs<DocType>(Query.EQ("age", 33));
cursor.SetFields(Fields.Include("a", "b"));
var items = cursor.ToList();
```

I have got that code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704290/mongodb-c-get-only-an-specifield-field) in stackoverflow.

But it throws an exception-

```
"Element '_id' does not match any field or property of class"
```

I don't want '_id' field in my POCO. Any help?

Comment: I think _id is included by default. Have you tried using cursor.SetFields(Fields.Exclude("_id")) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_id` is included in Fields by default.

You can exclude it by using something like:

```
cursor.SetFields(Fields.Exclude("_id"))
```