# C# and .NET MongoDB Driver: Retrieving distinct elements while setting a limit

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to retrieve a single property from all the documents in a collection. And a want a way to filter the result for a period while setting a limit and getting distinct values.

This is the way my documents look in the collection:

```
{
_id: [ObjectId],
number: [string],
timestamp: [Datetime]
}
```

Im using the 2.7 version of the driver.

So i want to retrive the **number** field distinct for documents in a specific period of the **timestamp** property. And while the _id property is bigger then a specific one...

The queries i tried so far are:

```
    var filter = Builders<Entity>.Filter.And(
        Builders<Entity>.Filter.Gte(entity => entity.timestamp, startDate),
        Builders<Entity>.Filter.Lte(entity => entity.timestamp, endDate),
        Builders<Entity>.Filter.Gte(entity => entity.Id, objectId));

    var query = collection
        .DistinctAsync(item => item.number, filter);
```

No way to set a limit?

```
    var filter = Builders<Entity>.Filter.And(
        Builders<Entity>.Filter.Gte(entity => entity.timestamp, startDate),
        Builders<Entity>.Filter.Lte(entity => entity.timestamp, endDate),
        Builders<Entity>.Filter.Gte(entity => entity.Id, lastObjectId));

    var query = collection
        .Find(filter)
        .Sort(Builders<Entity>.Sort.Ascending(entity => entity.number))
        .Project(entity => new {  entity.number})
        .Limit(100);
```

No way to get distinct values?

Because of the size of the collection i do not want to do any of these operation on the client.

Do anybody have a solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35595298/3966756 ?