# How do I make my generic method a way to choose which columns to return from mongoDB using C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

This is my method that returns all columns of the mongo, I need to adapt it to send parameters to choose the return columns.

```
    public virtual async Task<ListaFiltrada<TEntidade>> GetAllAsync(Paginacao paginacao = null, 
    Expression<Func<TEntidade, bool>> filtro = null, params Ordenacao<TEntidade>[] ordenacao)
    {
        if (!paginacao)
            paginacao = new Paginacao();

        var filtroEmBranco = new BsonDocument();
        var quantidade = await MongoCollection.CountDocumentsAsync(filtroEmBranco);
        var filtroMongo = filtro == null ? filtroEmBranco : Filtro.Where(filtro);
        var cursor = MongoCollection.Find(filtroMongo);

        if (ordenacao != null && ordenacao.Length > 0)
        {
            var ordem = new SortDefinition<TEntidade>[ordenacao.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < ordenacao.Length; i++)
                if (ordenacao[i].Ascendente)
                    ordem[i] = Ordenacao.Ascending(ordenacao[i].Campo);
                else
                    ordem[i] = Ordenacao.Descending(ordenacao[i].Campo);

            cursor.Sort(Ordenacao.Combine(ordem));
        }

        return new ListaFiltrada<TEntidade>
        {
            Total = quantidade,
            Pagina = paginacao.Pagina,
            TotalFiltrado = await cursor.CountDocumentsAsync(),
            Lista = await cursor.Skip(paginacao.Pular).Limit(paginacao.Quantidade).ToListAsync(),
        };
    }
```

I think of using some generic object as a parameter to send choose the columns that I want to return in the list.

If anyone has any questions or suggestions, I am available for more information :D

Answer (score 0):

Well guys, with the help of a good friend of mine Julius, I was able to do this in a very quiet way. Follow and, I attach the resolution

```
    public virtual async Task<ListaFiltrada<TEntidade>> GetAllAnyColumnAsync(Paginacao paginacao = null, Expression<Func<TEntidade, bool>> filtro = null,
        Expression<Func<TEntidade, TEntidade>> projectionExpression = null, params Ordenacao<TEntidade>[] ordenacao)
    {
        if (!paginacao)
            paginacao = new Paginacao();

        var filtroEmBranco = new BsonDocument();
        var quantidade = await MongoCollection.CountDocumentsAsync(filtroEmBranco);
        var filtroMongo = filtro == null ? filtroEmBranco : Filtro.Where(filtro);
        var cursor = projectionExpression == null ? MongoCollection.Find(filtroMongo) : MongoCollection.Find(filtroMongo).Project(projectionExpression);

        if (ordenacao != null && ordenacao.Length > 0)
        {
            var ordem = new SortDefinition<TEntidade>[ordenacao.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < ordenacao.Length; i++)
                if (ordenacao[i].Ascendente)
                    ordem[i] = Ordenacao.Ascending(ordenacao[i].Campo);
                else
                    ordem[i] = Ordenacao.Descending(ordenacao[i].Campo);

            cursor.Sort(Ordenacao.Combine(ordem));
        }

        if (ordenacao != null && ordenacao.Length > 0)
        {
            var ordem = new SortDefinition<TEntidade>[ordenacao.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < ordenacao.Length; i++)
                if (ordenacao[i].Ascendente)
                    ordem[i] = Ordenacao.Ascending(ordenacao[i].Campo);
                else
                    ordem[i] = Ordenacao.Descending(ordenacao[i].Campo);

            cursor.Sort(Ordenacao.Combine(ordem));
        }

        return new ListaFiltrada<TEntidade>
        {
            Total = quantidade,
            Pagina = paginacao.Pagina,
            TotalFiltrado = await cursor.CountDocumentsAsync(),
            Lista = await cursor.Skip(paginacao.Pular).Limit(paginacao.Quantidade).ToListAsync(),
        };
    }
```

I leave here a super save for my brother Julis who saved me with this help.
I hope this code helps somebody someday.

#Peace